# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas' No module named 'matplotlib.pyplot'

Tags: python, modulenotfounderror

I keep getting the error that the pandas module is not found as well as the matplotlib.pyplot module. I am pretty sure that I have both modules installed as I have used them both before. Why am i getting this error?
import pandas as pd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Read in the data from the CSV files and store them in dataframes
unemployment_df = pd.read_csv("UNRATE.csv", skiprows=1, names=["DATE", "UNEMPLOYMENT"])
cpi_df = pd.read_csv("CPIAUCSL.csv", skiprows=1, names=["DATE", "CPI"])
gdp_df = pd.read_csv("GDPC1.csv", skiprows=1, names=["DATE", "GDP"])

# Convert the DATE column to datetime format
unemployment_df["DATE"] = pd.to_datetime(unemployment_df["DATE"])
cpi_df["DATE"] = pd.to_datetime(cpi_df["DATE"])
gdp_df["DATE"] = pd.to_datetime(gdp_df["DATE"])

# Set the DATE column as the index for each dataframe
unemployment_df.set_index("DATE", inplace=True)
cpi_df.set_index("DATE", inplace=True)
gdp_df.set_index("DATE", inplace=True)

# Define a function to get the data for a specific time period
def get_data(start_year, end_year):
    start_date = pd.to_datetime(str(start_year))
    end_date = pd.to_datetime(str(end_year))
    unemployment_data = unemployment_df[start_date:end_date]
    cpi_data = cpi_df[start_date:end_date]
    gdp_data = gdp_df[start_date:end_date + pd.DateOffset(months=2)].resample("M").ffill()
    return unemployment_data, cpi_data, gdp_data

# Get the user input for the time period
start_year = int(input("Enter the start year (yyyy): "))
end_year = int(input("Enter the end year (yyyy): "))

# Get the data for the specified time period
unemployment_data, cpi_data, gdp_data = get_data(start_year, end_year)

# Bar graph of unemployment rate
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
plt.bar(unemployment_data.index, unemployment_data["UNEMPLOYMENT"])
plt.title("Unemployment Rate")
plt.xlabel("Date")
plt.ylabel("Unemployment Rate (%)")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Either you're mistaken and the `pandas` module is not actually installed on your computer, or it's installed for a different version of python than you are using to run your code.

Comment: As a start, show us the exact command you used to install the pandas module, and show us exactly how you run this code.

Answer (score 0):

Run `pip install` first before run that code

- On python cmd :

```
pip install pandas
pip install matplotlib
```

- On your computer's cmd :

```
python -m pip install pandas
python -m pip install matplotlib
```

Comment: I tried that and it just says Requirement already satisfied

Comment: Have you tested your code in [google colab](https://colab.research.google.com/)?

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall it, I guess this is due to you have two versoins of python and you installed those packages in one of them while you are using another one.

Check the interpreter and install packages using

```
pip install pandas matplotlib
```